# Viewer issue in UWP WebView

Tags: uwp, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am considering using the Forge Viewer within a UWP application via the UWP WebView. The viewer loads and the model is initially shown but then the actual model disappears and only the background of the viewer and the model shadow is shown.

This [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOLseWCKMZM) shows the issue. The sample app shown in the video can be created by using the blank page template and simply adding a Webview to the main page. I am simply using one of the forge samples to illustrate this issue. With simpler models sometimes it won't disappear immediately but always disappears after the user starts to rotate and/or zoom the model.

Any idea what is going on or how to fix this issue? My understanding is that the WebView uses the Edge rendering engine but yet this issue does not exist when viewing the same models within Edge.

**Edit**: Per the question in the comments, below are images of the console logs for both the original sample shown and the viewer-rocks page. FYI, I found the issue because it is doing this with the base viewer with my own content. In the demo I just wanted to use something publicly accessible.

[image: Original sample log]
[image: Viewer-rocks log]

Comment: Is there any way you could intercept console logs coming from the JavaScript code inside the WebView?

Comment: Also, could you try some other websites using the viewer, e.g., https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io, and see if they demonstrate the same behavior?

Comment: @PetrBroz I have edited the post above to include the console logs for both the original sample and the viewer rocks sample.

Comment: Thanks for the console logs, @Chris. Are you able to reproduce the same issue with https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io? I'd suggest using some simple viewer setup for now. Forge RCDB uses some advanced technologies/libraries (e.g., WebSockets, React) that will make it more difficult to find the root cause.

Comment: Yes the issue absolutely occurs with viewer-rocks.autodesk.io. This issue has nothing to do with Forge RCDB. It is occurring with the base viewer when displaying my own very simple content. I just was trying to demonstrate the issue with an example that you can verify easily works in Edge but yet doesn't work in the UWP Webview.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I've spent some time debugging the viewer in a UWP WebView, and I'm able to reproduce the same behavior - any 3D or 2D content disappears after a couple of rendered frames. It seems that it's only the actual model that disappears, other WebGL elements (e.g., shadows and background shaders) still work. The viewer uses a lot of advanced GPU techniques, so perhaps the UWP WebView fails because some of them.

Comment: Could you please send an email to forge [dot] help [at] autodesk [dot] com? I don't think the Forge Viewer supports UWP WebView officially, but we could forward your request to the dev. team to see what they're thinking.

Comment: Email has been sent. Thanks